# Double Flash on ESP32-S3 Board

Tags: double, esp32, flash-memory

We have designed and manufactured a new board. We have 8 MB of flash inside the ESP32-S3 (FN8 Model).
We also have 16 MB of flash (WINBOND W25Q128JVSIQ) on the board next to ESP32-S3.

Our problem is the bootloop. We use Arduino to load simple "Hello" program. But program is not reachable. It loops continiously in the boot partition. Our partition table is attached. It may not be appropriate.

How can we have correct partition table for double flashes (8 MB internal  of ESP32 + 16 MB external of ESP32)?

How can we customize the bootloader.bin file for our configuration?

Any help to solve this problem is appreciated.

[Our Partition Table for 8 MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vlrfh.png)

We have tried many boatloader.bin files, but no success.

[Messages from COM port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Irs.png)

[Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvm1R.png)

Comment: What's the output from the bootloader?

Comment: Messages from COM port:

Comment: I added messages from COM port to the end of my original post.

Comment: I added schematic as well

Answer (score 1):

Schematic shows the external Flash chip to be connected to SPI0. From how I interpret [data sheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_datasheet_en.pdf) section 3.5.2 it seems that the Flash chips should live on separate SPI buses - SPI0 for internal, SPI1 for the external Flash.

Comment: Thank you very much Tarmo. This issue is closed.